# how to set the badgevalue in tabbar in iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using the following code to set the badgevalue in current tab bar but its not visible in tab bar

```
self.navigationController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"1"
```

what is the correct way of putting the badge value in the tab bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you figure out why this `self.navigationController.tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"1"` didn't work? I got the same problem but didn't know why.
But this way it works:

```
[[[[self tabBarController] tabBar] items] objectAtIndex:0] setBadgeValue:@"AB"];
```

Answer (score 3):

This is how I access the badgeValue on a tabBarItem:

```
UITabBarItem * tabBarItem = (UITabBarItem *)[aTabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"1";
```