# How do you set the badgeValue for UITabBarItem to 3

Tags: objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I have ran into an error on trying to access the item in the array and set the badgeValue to 3. I've been checking out the documentation, but havent seem to be able to connect the dots. I feel i'm close but yet not close. The last two lines in my code below seem to wrong. And the following paragraph is the directions for this Task. I initially was thinking the last two lines were suppose to be in one line, but I believe its two because I have to access the array first then assign 3 to the badgeValue. Well, I little guide to the light would be very helpful. I'm sure i'll be kicking myself when I get down to the bottom of this.

Tabs have a property named 'badgeValue' that displays text in a red circle in the upper-right corner of the tab, like the number badges on the App Store or Messages apps. The tabs (UITabBarItems) are already stored in an array named 'tabBarItems'. Access the item in the array that corresponds to the selected index and then set the badge value to '3' for that UITabBarItem. Remember that 'badgeValue' must be an NSString!

```
#import "MainViewController.h"
#import "UITabBarItem.h"

@implementation MainViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSArray *tabBarItems = self.tabBarController.tabBar.items;

    // Add your code below! The property for MainViewController's 
    // tab bar controller is named 'tabBarController'.

    [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];
    [self.tabBarItems badgeValue:@"3"];
    [self.tabBarItems objectAtIndex:2];
    [self.tabBarItems.badgeValue string:3];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with this

```
UITabBarItem * tabBarItem = (UITabBarItem *)[aTabBarController.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:1];
tabBarItem.badgeValue = @"1";
```

I took it from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2392054/1136433)

Comment: You can also retrieve it from within the corresponding viewController via the `tabBarItem` property.

Answer (score 0):

```
 let tabBarArray = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items as! NSArray
        let thirdTab = tabBarArray.object(at: 3) as! UITabBarItem
        thirdTab.badgeValue = "3"
```

First create a tab bar array so that you can access the third tab. Then create a variable for that tab and update the badge value to 3. Works perfectly.